# Running Same Java Program on Multiple Compute Nodes

Tags: java, jvm, multiple-instances

Assume a java program `dir/program.class`. I want to run many instances of the program at the same time from different compute nodes in a cluster. Namely,

- `ssh compute-1`, `cd dir`, `java program resource1.txt output1.txt`
- `ssh compute-2`, `cd dir`, `java program resource2.txt output2.txt`
- `ssh compute-3`, ...

Each run of `program` takes several hours and performs numerical tests.
Is there any drawback I should consider? In order to have sound results each instance should not be "disturbed" by the others. Will these instances interfere in each others calculations in any way? 
Notice that they consume and produce resources in different files, so no problem with concurrent access to those files. The only thing they share is the class files. Can that be a problem in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're on different nodes, they won't share class files either. Unless they explicitly connect to other nodes, they have no way of interfering (or communicating) with each other.